# JAVA maven clean install test not finishing iterator

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, iterator, mockito

I have simple script that reads a file:

```
 /**
 * Takes a txt file with all songs listed in music directory
 * and saves this to the songs database
 */
public void rebuildFromFilelist() {
    final List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(songsfile));
        sc.useDelimiter("\r?\n|\r");
        sc.forEachRemaining(l -> getSongFromLine(songs, l)); //function constructs a Song object

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error("Error in processing file: {}", songsfile);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    songs.forEach(song -> log.debug(song.toString())); 

    songRepository.saveAll(songs);
}
```

Then i have a test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class SongRepositoryServiceTest {


@Autowired
private SongRepositoryService songRepositoryService;

@Test
@DisplayName("Rebuild library from file")
void RebuildLibraryWithFile() {
    songRepositoryService.rebuildLibraryWithFile();
    final List<Song> songs = songRepositoryService.findByCategory(Song.SongCategory.SONG);
    final List<Song> others = songRepositoryService.findByCategory(Song.SongCategory.OTHER);

    assertFalse(songs.isEmpty());
    assertFalse(others.isEmpty());
}
}
```

The file that I'm processing is about 620 items long. The first 400 are of category SONG, the rest is category OTHER.

When I run the test from Intellij, the test succeeds. However, if I run it during mvn clean install, it only processes the first 155 items and stops (thus failing the second assertion).

Why is this? How can I fix this, or even debug this?

Regards,

Barbet

EDIT:
The failing test only reports this, no errors or stacktraces:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.gsm.GsmWeb.service.SongRepositoryServiceTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 6, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.161 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.gsm.GsmWeb.service.SongRepositoryServiceTest
com.gsm.GsmWeb.service.SongRepositoryServiceTest.RebuildLibraryWithFile  Time elapsed: 0.532 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <false> but was: <true>
    at com.gsm.GsmWeb.service.SongRepositoryServiceTest.RebuildLibraryWithFile(SongRepositoryServiceTest.java:88)
```

Comment: Any stacktrace or other information when the processing "stops" ?

Comment: The strange part is that the service does not throw any errors during the build and test run. The only reason I see the iterator stops at 155 is because of the log line that i put in:

    songs.forEach(song -> log.debug(song.toString()));  The test then fails on the assertion : assertFalse(others.isEmpty());

Comment: So likely reasons. 1 a different file used, maybe different working directory. `log.info( new File(songfile).getCanonicalPath() );'  and compare the filenames. 2. the file is broken maybe caused by encoding problem (is something special with song 156 ?). can you provide the content of song 155 and 156?

Comment: change  `e.printStackTrace();` to `new RuntimeException(e);` to let the exception escape have it displayed. Maybe also do `log.error("Error processing", e);`

Comment: I've tried the error change to new RuntimeException, but there is still no error being thrown. No success. There is nothing strange about line 155, and actually it's now failing on 139. The dataset is private, but I'll try to get a representative dataset to support my question.

Comment: Another likely problem is that the file is modified by a different test.

Comment: How can I test that? What drives me nuts is that the test succeeds when running the test class. The file seems to be cut off during the mvn clean install build. I got it to throw an error when the song object could not be constructed. It seems to read the line only partially: "004 this is a song.mp3; OTHER;" becomes "004 this is a song.mp". Removing the specific line in the file does not help, the problem than just occurs on the next line (or any other line you put on line 140).

Comment: One way would be to log the complete file content before you parse it. Something like 'Log.debug(new String(Files.readAllBytes(new File(songsfile).toPath()))));'

Comment: I gave up. I looked for another solution and implemented:             
Files.lines(new File(songsfile).toPath()).forEach(l -> getSongFromLine(songs, l));

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems some problem with the maven build in relation to the java Scanner iterator. I could not debug it as it was very flaky. I solved the problem by replacing the

`Files.lines(new File(songsfile).toPath()).forEach(l -> getSongFromLine(songs, l));`

Now everything works perfectly.